# Why is override_function coming back as an undefined function

Tags: php

I run:

> override_function('test_func', '$a, $b', 'print_r("new");');

and I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function override_function()

I am using php 5.3.26

Comment: And since when you can use functions without declarations? I guess you need module that provides `override_function`

Comment: override_function is part of `Advanced PHP debugger` - do you have that installed?

Answer (score 6):

Function `override_function` is part of PECL Extension.

Configure [**PECL**](http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php) Here.